# How to manage two type of json in the same class?

Tags: c#, json

I have this json structure:

```
[{"trace":{"details":{"date":"[28-02-2016 11:04:26.856573]","type":"[info]","message":"[system done.]"},"context":{"context":[[{"ID":"john dillinger"}]]}}},{"trace":{"details":{"date":"[28-02-2016 11:04:26.856728]","type":"[info]","message":"[trace done.]"},"context":{"context":[[{"ID":"john dillinger"}]]}}}]
```

I can deserialize it correctly using this class:

```
public class Trace
{
    public TraceValue trace;
}

public class TraceValue
{
    public Details details;
    public Context context;
}

public class Details
{
    public String date;
    public String type;
    public String message;
}

public class Context
{
    public List<List<IdItem>> context;
}

public class IdItem
{
    public String ID;
}
```

an example of deserialization:

```
var response = "json above";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Trace>>(response);
```

now the problem is that sometimes the json is returned with this structure:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "No content."
}
```

my code fall in error 'cause the structure is different. I tried to read the header but is returned as 200 'cause no error happean. So how can I recognize the different structure and avoid the json exception? This is the class to manage the different json structure:

```
 public class RootObject
 {
      public bool success { get; set; }
      public string message { get; set; }
 }
```

I could do this in the exception but this isn't a good practice, there is another way?

Comment: Does the standard message include `"success": true`?

Comment: the message is returned only in the second case, if there is a content I get the full stack "trace", also I get the `success: false` and the relative `message`

Comment: In that case, there's no reason for there to even be a `success` parameter, if it's always `false` if it exists. Do you have any control over the input?

Comment: No control, I simply get the json returned and deserialize it, the problem is that if another structure is returned I can't deserialize the json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a case like yours, the better is to first obtain a JToken and then check if it has the message property and deserialize to the correct object:

```
var container = (JContainer)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

var message = container["message"];

if(message == null)
{
    var obj = container.ToObject<List<Trace>>();

    //Do whatever you need to do with the object
}
else
{
    var msg = container.ToObject<RootObject>();

    //Do whatever you need to do with the object
}
```

Comment: the only problem is that if there is content I get this exception: `System.ArgumentException: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "message"` but in general the solution working.

Comment: Strange, a JToken (JContainer is a JToken) should return null if it does not have a key, maybe it's because the response is just an array, then if that's the case you can do "if(container is JArray)"

Comment: You're right now working. I want to ask: you think that I should return at the top of the json the status and the message ever? So I can simply check this before continue the deserialization?

Comment: Well, that's the better you can do, add always the success boolean, then you can check it, if it's true deserialze the data, if it's false deserialze the message.

Answer (score -1):

Not a proper way but I have done this.

Convert the generated json object in to string. And edit the string to make the same format.

Than you can parse both string which are in same format